# Does vagrant share with https still work?

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox, sni, vagrant-plugin

- I have the guest's `HTTPS` port set to 443 on it's Apache 2 installation.
- In `Vagrantfile`

  - I have `vm.forwarded_port` set to forward from 443 to 8443
  - I have `vm.hostname` set to `actualdomain.org`
- I've also installed the `vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater` so that `actualdomain.org` is written to my `hosts` file, so it pulls up the developer environment and not the actual site when it is requested.
- List item

  1. I ran `vagrant connect`...
  2. I ran `vagrant share --https 443 --domain actualdomain.org` but it reports the following:

  ==> default: Detecting network information for machine...
      default: Local machine address: 192.168.xx.10
      default: Local HTTPS port: 443
  ==> default: Checking authentication and authorization...
  ==> default: Creating Vagrant Share session...
  There was an error returned by the Vagrant Cloud server. The
  error message is shown below:

  - Domain cannot be used with this account

But if I run `vagrant share` without the `--domain` parameter, I end up with the following in my logs when I try to contact the site remotely:

```
Hostname XXXXX-YYY-ZZZZ provided via SNI and hostname XXXXX-YYY-ZZZZ.vagrantshare.com provided via HTTP are different
```

And in the browser I am returned an HTTP 400 Bad Request.

Is there any easy way around this?  It seems to me that this didn't happen the last time I used vagrant, and it seems as though there was something added to TLS that causes it to balk about the SNI error since then.

I even tried adding a server alias that was the same as the XXXXX-YYY-ZZZ.vagrantshare.com, and it still is giving me an issue; does that mean that I have to rebuild the certificate everytime the hashicorp URL changes if I want to show it off to somebody via their browser?

Comment: Oh give me a break...why the down vote?

Comment: It seems that it doesn't currently work with Apache. I think Apache considers the SNI host vs HTTP host mismatch behaviour of `vagrant share` a browser bug, and returns a 400 error. Nginx seemingly doesn't care. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI